# LAravel Query Builder - A little different Where Query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a **project** table like this-

[image: asdf]

I want to select all data with company ID 0 and 2 (company ID may be 1,3,3,4,5,6,...).

So, what I have done in Laravel Query Builder is -

```
 DB::table( 'project')
      ->where('project.is_archived', '=', 0)
      ->where('project.companyID', '=', 0)
      ->orwhere('project.companyID', '=', 2)
      ->get;
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 DB::table('project')
    ->where('is_archived', 0)
    ->whereIn('companyID', [0, 2])
    ->get();
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to mimo's solution, you can also combine statements using callbacks or the special `where` methods.

So something like:

```
DB::table('project')
    ->where('is_archived', 0)
    ->orWhere(function(Builder $query) {
        $query
            ->where('companyID', 0)
            ->where('companyID', 2)
    });
```

would create this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE (is_archived = 0) AND (companyID = 0 OR companyID = 2)
```

You could also do that with a simple `->where(function($query) {})` where you change the `$boolean` argument of the encapsulated `where()` statements to 'or' (which can allow for much more complex statements)

See the Laravel 5.1 Docs for [Parameter Grouping](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#advanced-where-clauses)